# How to validate a Lua Pattern Matching generator

Tags: lua, pattern-matching

I'm doing a lua code generator, it's simple, user could give me a pattern (like "/myUrl/%d") and then I have to create a lua code that will run into nginx.

So I create something like this.

```
if string.match("/myUrl/12","/myUrl/%d+")
    ANOTHER CODE HERE
end
```

Thats works, but I would like to check if that pattern is valid, So I've decided to run a validation before to create that code as:

> lua -e 'string.match("fake","/%")'

**This is OK**

> lua -e 'string.match("/myfake","/%")'

```
lua: (command line):1: malformed pattern (ends with '%')
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'match'
    (command line):1: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

**This will fail**

So I would like to know if there is some way to check pattern matching without provide an example string to match.

Comment: `if not pcall(string.match, "", your_pattern) then print"Invalid Pattern" end`

Comment: lua -e 'if not pcall(string.match, "/aa", "/%") then print"Invalid Pattern" end' it's return as valid.

Comment: and this is valid for him lua -e 'if not pcall(string.match, "/aa", "/%d") then print"Invalid Pattern" end'